# Roman numerals for sections and subsections

Tags: sectioning, numbering, roman-numerals

I want to have my sections numbered using Roman numerals. However, I can only get the section number to be a Roman numeral, not the subsection. Here is some code:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Roman{subsection}}
```

This will print, e.g. I. , whereas it should be I.I.  Commenting out the second line gives the result I.1, which is not demanded.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to append the `section` number to the `subsection` number using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: Section and subsection numbering]

Answer (score 17):

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}
```

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for the 3rd tier (`subsubsection`) but couldn't find it anywhere. I managed to figure it out though. So, for anyone who's in the same spot as i was, here is the `subsubsection` version:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesection.\thesubsection.\Roman{subsubsection}}
```

Comment: You will get the section number twice, if `\thesubsection` is defined as in the answers (`\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}`). Then `\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\Roman{subsubsection}}` will do the trick.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek good observation, the original answer is incorrect without your comment.