# The command \year gives a number instead of text. How is it done?

Tags: numbering, datetime

As I know, in the command sequence `\the\year`, `\year` gives a number, and `\the` converts it to text.

What I don't understand is, how to make a command that results in a number but not a piece of text representing that number, like the command `\year`?

In other words, if I want `\theXXX` to generate "1234" (without quotes), what do I replace `XXX` with?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you mean here. `\the\year` yields the year as a number (currently "2011"), while `\year` may be used directly in places where TeX expects a number. Perhaps you mean the fact that `\year` is similar in effect to a TeX count register?

Comment: @JosephWright: Hope the edit helps explaining my question.

Comment: are you thinking of \value{XXX} (where XXX is the counter name)? or are you not actually using latex?

Comment: @Anon: I found \value{XXX} is what I'm looking for. I'm new to latex. Sorry if my question looks stupid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question appears to be more about accessing a counter's value than dates. whlt3 has provided some details on that. Here is an example based on [What is the proper method of accessing a counter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/what-is-the-proper-method-of-accessing-a-counter).

### Counters:

You declare a counter with `\newcounter{XXX}`, set the counters value with `\setcounter{XXX}{1234}`. Then you can access it as `\theXXX`, or `\the\value{xxxx}`, and both produce the same output:

[image]

You can change the desired formatting of the counters output via `\renewcommand{\theXXX}{\Roman{XXX}}`, after which `\theXXX` results in the counter's value being displayed in roman numerals:

[image]

This technique is often used to change the style of chapter/section, etc... numbers.  See for example [Roman numerals for sections and subsections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26882/roman-numerals-for-sections-and-subsections).

### Dates:

If you are interested in specifically formatting and manipulating dates, you should consider

- [the `datetime` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datetime) for formatting dates
- [the `datenumber` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datenumber) for conversion from conversion between dates to numbers

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{XXX}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{XXX}{1234}
\textbackslash{}theXXX yields \theXXX\par
\textbackslash{}the\textbackslash{}value yields \the\value{XXX}

\bigskip
\renewcommand{\theXXX}{\Roman{XXX}}
\textbackslash{}theXXX yields \theXXX\par
\textbackslash{}the\textbackslash{}value yields \the\value{XXX}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

`\year` does not just give a *number*; it gives an *internal integer*. This is one of the types of integers that TeX knows. Together with the *denotation integers* (these are just strings of digits, possibly converted between bases) they are known as the *normal integers*. Besides the normal integers there are also *coerced integers*, which occur when an internal glue or dimen is coerced to an integer.

TeX goes implicitly from a string of digits to a number, that is, if TeX expects a number then anything that looks like a number is accepted. So 42 is a number. The other way around has to be done explicitly though, either through `\romannumeral` or `\number`. When we are dealing with an internal integer, `\the` is equivalent to `\number`. Since you ask what you can use for `XXXX` when you want `\theXXXX` to print something, the answer is an internal integer. There are quite a lot, the ones that you can easily influence are tokens defined by `chardef` or `mathdef` and the contents of `count` registers.

For non-internal integers you want to use `\number` instead though. That is to say, `\number123` will compile fine, where `\the123` will fail.

Comment: Good answer. You are opening a Pandora's box with `\number`, which will expand further than you may expect in some cases.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Yeah, there should be a `\relax` there. At least, I presume that is what you mean `:-)`.

Comment: Yes. Or a space. Or any non-expandable thing other than an explicit digit with category code other. `\relax` is the simplest thing to put.