# A list of equations in a algorithm box

Tags: equations, formatting, algorithms

I want to have something like this image. Can someone help me please?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get started, there are a few things you will need to take into consideration.

The horizontal rules, the aligned equation environment, the roman numerals for the sections, and the section.eqn# format for your equations.

Here are some great resources for all your requirements:

Horizontal rules: [Horizontal line spanning the entire document in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19579/horizontal-line-spanning-the-entire-document-in-latex/19582)

Aligned equations: [Aligning equations with amsmath](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/aligning_equations_with_amsmath)

Roman numerals for sections: [Roman numerals for sections and subsections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26882/roman-numerals-for-sections-and-subsections)

Section.eqn# format for equations: [Change the type of equation numbering in document class article [duplicate]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54241/change-the-type-of-equation-numbering-in-document-class-article)

I hope this helps!

**UPDATE:**

As I technically used the answer feature and didn't comment, I was expected to actually give OP a full solution, so here goes!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.8pt}}
\textbf{Formulation VI} Exercise 1.5 \\[-1ex]
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\begin{align}
    & & & & \min \ \sum_{o \in O}\sum_{c \in C}d_{co}x_{co} \tag{VI.1} \\
    & & \text{s.t.} & & \qquad \sum_{o \in O} x_{co} & \leq 9 & {} & \forall c \in C \tag{VI.2} \\
    & & & & \sum_{o \in O}x_{co}     & \geq 5                 & {} & \forall c \in C \tag{VI.3} \\
    & & & & \sum_{o \in O}m_o x_{co} & \geq 1                 & {} & \forall c \in C \tag{VI.4} \\
    & & & & \sum_{c \in C}x_{co}     & =  1                   & {} & \forall o \in O \tag{VI.5} \\
    & & & & x_{co}                   & \in \left\{0,1\right\} & {} & \forall c \in C,\ \forall o \in O \tag{VI.6}
\end{align}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.8pt}}
\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX output]

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your comprehensive list of ressources that will surely help the OP. But this is not considered as an answer and should remain as a comment.

Comment: @SebGlav I cannot comment, I guess I'll just write everything out.