# section numbering in turabian-researchpaper

Tags: sectioning

I'm trying to find a way for the
\section{} command in the turabian-researchpaper environment to show a section number in Roman Numerals. What can I do to do that?

Comment: Maybe try `\roman{counter}` or `\Roman{counter}` ?

Answer (score 1):

In principle the approach is the same as for the `article` class, on which `turabian-researchpaper` is based, see for example [Roman numerals for sections and subsections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26882/roman-numerals-for-sections-and-subsections). The answer to that question redefines the `\section` and `\subsection` counter display macros (which are `\thesection` and `\thesubsection`, respectively) as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}
```

However, `turabian-researchpaper` sets the section numbering depth to 0, which means that sections and everything below that (subsection, subsubsection, paragraph) are not numbered. Therefore you need to modify that too, for example set it to 2 in order to number sections and subsections in line with the redefinitions above.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{turabian-researchpaper}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]